# Change java version in master node of dataproc

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

I have created a dataproc cluster in Google cloud and in the master node I can see the java version as 8.

I need to use Java version 11, How can we do that.

Can we edit in the existing cluster or Can we specify it while creating a new cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Dataproc doesn't support changing Java version at runtime or cluster creation time. If you really want to change the Java version, consider creating a [custom image](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-images) with the Java version you want. But note that Dataproc packages in 1.5 and 2.0 are built with Java 8, so you might run into compatibility issues.

BTW, Dataproc Serverless Spark is Java 11 based [1](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/concepts/versions/spark-runtime-versions).